# FCM background/not running notification getIntent().getExtra() has mMap allways null

Tags: android, push-notification, background, bundle

I'm working on an app in which i get from the server some push notifications when some events are triggered.

When the application is in foreground all works great, in the onMessageReceived() i get the remoteMessage and handle it based on its map key value.

The problem is in background or when the application is not running...I still get the notification in the device screen, and when i tap on it the activity starts.

I do the following verification after the activity starts:

```
 Bundle mBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(mBundle != null)
    {
    //do stuff
    }
```

But i always get the mMap = null in the bundle object which means i cannot handle properly the push notification.

[image]

Can something be done about this ?

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? I'm having the same problem, although in my case, mMap used to be non-null when the app was started by a notification tap. Then, all of a sudden without changing any of the code, mMap was null.

Answer (score -1):

There are two types of [Notification Message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options)

**1. Notification message**

Notification Message can be fetched when application is running, but if the application is not running(killed) then it will not work. It only shows that notification is arrived.

example,

```
{
  "message":{
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "notification":{
      "title":"Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "body":"great match!"
    }
  }
}
```

**2. Data message** (also known as silent notification)

Whereas Data Messagegs works even if the application is not running.

example,

```
{
  "message":{
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "data":{
      "Nick" : "Mario",
      "body" : "great match!",
      "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: how can i confirm that the one sent when the app is in background is a data message ?

Comment: I down-voted this answer because it doesn't address the OP's question at all.