# onMessageReceived() not calling when FCM notification Received

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my project, I have to receive FCM push notification when the app is running `onMessageReceived()` is calling an app working well but the problem is When app killed or in background onMessageReceived() is not calling but `FCM` notification is displaying on Notification tray

Comment: In that case your launcher activity will handle the notification Not onMessageReceived() method.

Comment: @Tharun When FCM message is send using notification type, you won't receive message in onMessageReceived() method when your app is not running

Comment: Thank you @HasifSeyd but i have to that handle that case can you please help me on that

Comment: @Tharun But When you click on the notification from notification tray , you will get the data as Bundle in the Launch Activity which would be assigned when sending push notification from the server

Comment: @Tharun, Please check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49152652/996493)

Comment: @HasifSeyd Yes i was try to handle the bundle in launcher activity but am not succeed on that , I think i am confuse which strings i have to take from that bundle

Comment: @HasifSeyd i was tried one more case on In launcher activity i was taken flag values(if (flag == 335544320 || flag == 67108864 || flag == 339738624) {
// my conditions on ths block
}) if FCM notification is received i got various issues Some time working well and some times failure in some device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, you need to use `data` payload alone, example:

```
"data": {
"titles": "New Title",
"bodys": "body here"
}
```

since if you use data payload it will enter `onMessageRecieved()` if the application was in the foreground or background.

Then in `FCM` you can do the following to receive the data:

```
 if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {

    title = remoteMessage.getData().get("titles");
    body = remoteMessage.getData().get("bodys");
}
```

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages

Comment: Thank you @Peter Haddad i was tried this but remote message size is not getting when app is killed

Comment: yes it does not work in all phones when app is killed, check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39505298/7015400

Comment: Thank ou @Peter Haddad I thinkthis link is helpful to me